# how to get the last word C of 'A→B→C' in SQL mysql or psql

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

how to get the last string C of 'A→B→C' in SQL mysql or psql

```
data
A→B→C
A→B→C→D
B→C→D
B→F
E→B→C→G→H
A
```

and my expected output is the last word of the above data:

```
data
C
D
D
F
H
A
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Postgres you can use `substring()` with a regex:

```
substring(data from '→([^→]+)$')
```

If you don't know your delimiter (which again shows what a really bad idea it is to store delimited strings) you can use a different regex:

```
substring(data from '\W([\w]+)$')
```

That uses "non-word" characters as the delimiter

Or split the column into an array:

```
(string_to_array(data, '→'))[cardinality(string_to_array(data, '→'))]
```

[Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=34c448fb93667bee443b997752f617c1)

Comment: But maybe you don't know what the separators are, in which case it might be safer to articulate the regex as getting letters at the end.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: but if you don't know the delimiter, you can't really extract values from a delimited string ;)

Comment: `substring(data from '→([^→]+)$')` hi, this works in some code, but I also have some data does't have `→`

Comment: @FIREUSD: so which other delimiters do you have?

Comment: I added a case when in your code, then it works

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL 8+, you may use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` here:

```sql
SELECT data, REGEXP_SUBSTR(data, '[A-Z]+$') AS last_data
FROM yourTable;
```

On Postgres, which doesn't have an exact `REGEXP_SUSBTR` function, we can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` instead:

```sql
SELECT data, REGEXP_REPLACE(data, '^.*[^A-Z]', '') AS last_data
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

On MySQL, the above regex replacement option should also work.

Comment: Postgres does have a `regexp_substr()` - it's just `substring()`

Comment: hi, where to put `→`?

Comment: @FIREUSD You don't need it.  I phrased your requirement as saying you want the final letters in each of your `A->B->...` paths.

Comment: but in my postgresql, they all return a null string ''

Comment: My Postgres answer definitely works in the demo.  My guess is that your data has some problem.

Comment: Oh the original data is `A234.2→B234.3→C134.1`

Comment: Use: `REGEXP_REPLACE(data, '^.*[^A-Z0-9.]', '')` ... Here is [your updated demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=80835622949eb0c77d24bbb5acc5b92b)

Answer (score 0):

You can also easy use **SUBSTRING_INDEX** like this:

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX("A→B→C", "→", -1);

RESULT: "C"